# Rotativa works in localhost but wont work in my Azure Web App - 2021

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-webapps, rotativa

*Disclaimer: I know there are other questions like this but all seems to be very old and I don't know if this is a new issue in Azure.*

I have a small *C# MVC web app* that list some laboratory test result and let the user download the result as a PDF. I've always used **Rotativa** for this kind of stuffs, and never encountered a problem.

The feature works like a charm in localhost, but when I deploy to my Web App in Azure it wont load and the server times out. I've tried everything and wont work, I installed Rotativa has a Nuget in my project version 1.7.3.

And this is how I'm creating the pdf:

```
public ActionResult Pdf()
{
     var file = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("~/Views/CovidTest/TestViewForPDF.cshtml", null) { FileName = "Test.pdf", PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4, CustomSwitches = "--disable-smart-shrinking" };         
        
     return file;
}
```

This is the first time I'm  having this issue in Azure. I don't know if there is something I'm missing in the Web App configuration.

Comment: Have you added any exception handling and logging?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'm having a similar issue trying to deploy an app service which uses Rotativa.ViewAsPDf. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for me in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682110/azure-websites-and-wkhtmltopdf).

My testing App Service was using the D1 Shared plan. As soon as I scaled it up to a production plan - e.g. S1 - it worked.